# Как удалить папку с фото в Firebase Storage. Next.js?

Tags: typescript, firebase, next.js, storage

Всех приветствую. Возник вопрос. При создание товара, создаю в Storage папку с фото товара.
Название папки генерирует uid(), который есть и в объекте товара.
При нажатии удалить товар, мне нужно удалять папку с фото, чтобы не засорять Storage.
По uid папку находит.
Но мне нужен код, который удаляет папку, а не один файл.
Знаю то, чтобы удалить файл - нужна такая функция

```js
const desertRef = ref(storage, `images/${uid}/product.png`);
deleteObject(desertRef).then(() => {
   return
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

А чтобы удалить папку с файлами, не знаю.
Подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел ответ на свой вопрос.
Папку вряд-ли разрешит удалить, но достать файлы, и удалить по очереди можно, а папка если пуста - удаляется автоматически.
Ответ нашел здесь:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37749647/firebasestorage-how-to-delete-directory